# stack calculation in microcontroller

Tags: embedded, stack

I have written a program to estimate the stack usage in the following manner
I have defined a global pointer variable to unsigned char. I have defined a local variable in the main program and have taken the address of this variable which will be my starting stack location. In every subroutine I go I will define my known variable and take the address of this variable. The difference between
the first stack location and the new stack location will be my size from which I can calculate the maximum stack size.

```
unsigned char *startingstacklocation;
unsigned char *endingstacklocation;
unsigned int maxstacksize; 

int main()
{
unsinged char mydefinedlocalvariable;
startingstacklocation = &mydefinedlocalvariable; 
subroutine1();
}

void subroutine1(void)
{
unsigned char existingvariables[20];
unsigned char mydefinedlocalvariable;

endingstacklocation = &mydefinedlocalvariable;
stacksize = endingstacklocation  - startingstacklocation;
if(stacksize > maxstacksize)
{
 maxstacksize = stacksize;
}
}
```

My question is it the proper way of doing?

Comment: For which uC are you compiling? I wrote a Python script that calculates the stack use from the .lss output of the gcc, so far for Cortex-M and AVR (mega328), and a start for the MSP430. It isn't perfect, but it might suit your needs.

Comment: that will only work only if you aren't using any interrupts.

Comment: i am trying for freescale s12x micro controller.

Comment: A pity, I don't have support for those chips, and it doesn't seem to be fully supported by gcc (?), so it is unlikely that I'd add it in the future.

Comment: Just wanted to understand python script will do the stack calculation at run time or stand alone. I am sorry if i did not understand properly.

Comment: Standalone. It reads the assembler output of the compiler, constructs the call tree and the local stack use of each function, and from that it calculated the maximum stack size. (And with some additional makescript steps, creates a stack of that size and links the application with that stack. Allocated at the bottom of RAM, of course.) It has lots of limitations: no indirect calls (function pointers, C++ virtual, etc), no exceptions, no calculated-size locals arrays, etc. And as yet (but that can change): single thread only, and no interrupts.

Comment: One final doubt not fully supported by gcc. What exactly mean by this?

Answer (score 3):

This all depends on your compiler, the compiler options, and the microcontroller you are using. It *may* be a reasonable way to get an *approximation* of the stack usage, but it will not be completely accurate.

If you are running your code in an embedded operating system, it will often have the stack pointers for each thread readily accessible so that you can read it directly. If you are coding this on the "bare metal", then I suggest that you find out how to read the stack pointer directly, write an assembly code routine to read it out, and use that value in your checks. If you are using GCC, you can tell the compiler to embed this check at the start of *every* function automatically, using the "instrument-functions" option.

The way I often do it while developing is to allocate a lot of memory for the stack, then fill it with a special pattern that is unlikely to naturally appear in the stack. After my code has been running, I go through this area and search backwards until I reach the first value that is not my pattern, and then I can be pretty sure that this is the most stack that has been used. For this to be effective, you have to exercise all code paths during testing.

EDIT: I now see that you assume that the stack grows from a low address to a high address. This is often not the case. In particular, it is not true for your S12 microcontroller. Section 2.2.4 of the *S12CPUV2 Reference Manual* mentions that it grows from "downward", meaning that it starts out at a higher address and is decreased towards zero the more it is used.

Comment: It is fine for me if it is an approximate value. I tried reading stack pointer, i was not successful and also i got confused the frequency at which i have to read.

Comment: @rajesh - If at all possible use the stack memory pre-filled with a know value approach to getting stack usage. It is the only easy way to get to max stack usage when interrupts are taken into account.

Comment: I see now that you are using an S12 MCU. It has an instruction that is called "STS", which lets you store the stack pointer into a memory location. There is also the TSX instruction which copies the stack pointer to the X register. I have not (yet) written inline assembly for the S12 architecture, so I'm afraid I don't know exactly how such a function would look like, but that's how I would try to use them.

Comment: Oh, about the frequency you should read it: You can use it in each function as you have done already, or you can let gcc add it to every function automatically.